# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Takes Me Back to the Install Screen After Installing Via USB

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation

Basically, I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit), and attempted to install it via my flash drive.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), but after rebooting when prompted to, I was taken back to the installation screen, asking me to either Install Ubuntu or just try it. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu, since after the first install I booted into Windows Vista by accident and it did a disk check on where my Ubuntu partition was, but the same problem still occurs.

Also, after the USB installer initially finished, I noticed that the installer mentioned that a few items could not be written for whatever reason (memory, I believe, but I'm not completely certain). I feel that may be the stem of the problem, but I'm brand new to Linux and pretty much have no clue what I'm doing, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously, you're booting into the USB again.

Answer (score 1):

After install ubuntu reject your USB stcick and  then restart. **Unplug USB flash drive after ubuntu installation complete**

Answer (score 0):

After the install process, when the system restarts, enter BIOS (push hot-key designated by your hardware manual, on an HP it's F10), and change your boot order so it boots off the hard drive first. Save and exit the BIOS, system *should* boot Ubuntu.